# Codeigniter A3M Admin Controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-a3m

Hi I am trying to use **[CodeIgniter A3M](https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M)**.

I am trying to view the manage users and manage permission etc but keeps on saying error 404 I am the admin I have just created an account for my self.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? I assume you know what 404 means, probably setup CodeIgniter `.htaccess` incorrectly.. look at logs, make sure your rewrite is working and update your question, very little detail provided.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with your CodeIgniter setup. All the links in A3M are already assumes that you have taken steps to remove the `index.php` from the path using `.htaccess`. You can read in the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) on how to do that. In general you should have this in your .htaccess file in the root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Also check that you have all other settings set correctly [according to A3M](https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M/wiki/Installation-Instructions).

Answer (score 0):

**I think you must code .htacess file like this**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me

My code .htacess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php    
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)    
RewriteCond $1!^(index\.php|resource|system|user_guide|bootstrap|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```